# How can I automatically make ZFS filesyatems mount shared / rshared?

Tags: lxc, zfs, bind-mount

I have a number of ZFS sub-filesystems (so that I can granularly manage snapshots and ZFS options) like so:

```
tank/media
tank/media/pictures
tank/media/pictures/photos
tank/media/movies
tank/media/music
tank/media/documents
tank/media/documents/public
```

I am running Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie) with ZFS-on-Linux, kernel `4.4.19-1-pve`. My goal is to share the parent ZFS filesystem (`tank/media`) with a LXC container via a bind mount *and have the sub-filesystems be accessible*.

If I bind mount `tank/media` inside the container, then the sub ZFS filesystems (E.G. `tank/media/pictures`) do not show up. I need to `mount --make-rshared tank/media` in order for the sub-mounts to also appear.

How can I make ZFS sub filesystems be mounted `make-rshared` by default using ZFS on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that mounting with the `rbind` (rather than `bind`) option in the lxc mount line solves the issue (syntax for proxmox):

```
lxc.mount.entry: /tank/media media none rbind,create=dir,optional 0 0
```

[Going off the RedHat documentation on sharing mounts](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/sect-Using_the_mount_Command-Mounting-Bind.html), `rbind` achieves replication of mounts on the source in the bound directory (which is what we need), the difference being `make-rshared` allows a mount on the bind to be reflected in the source.

Just came across the issue myself, and this is the only relevant result on google, so I thought it was appropriate to give an answer despite the age of the question.

Comment: Had to wait until the next reboot of the server, but I tried this solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you!!!